# Load dataframe columns from CSV as strings only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert all columns of a csv file into str while reading with Pandas in python. What is the most efficient way to write this code?

```
df = pd.read_csv("datafile.csv", sep = "\s+", names = ["lvl12",
"etime", "press", "gph", "temp", "rh", "dpdp", "wdir", "wspd"])
df['lvl12'].astype(str)
df['etime'].astype(str)
df['press'].astype(str)
df['gph'].astype(str)
df['temp'].astype(str)
df['rh'].astype(str)
df['dpdp'].astype(str)
df['wdir'].astype(str)
df['wspd'].astype(str)
```

Comment: df=df.astype(str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one better; add the `dtype=str` argument when reading `df` in:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    "datafile.csv", 
    sep="\s+", 
    names=["lvl12", "etime", "press", ...],
    dtype=str
)
```

Comment: Yep , I am thinking of this way :-)

Comment: That's awesome! There are so many useful key-word arguments lurking in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can call astype on the whole dataframe at once:

`df.astype(str)`